# How to add a border to md-select selectbox of angular material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to add a 1px border to the select box ( md-select ) of angular material.

How do I do it using CSS?

Answer (score 7):

In latest angular versions, md-select is renamed as mat-select and to add border to mat-select, you can use mat-form-field in your html file as follows:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select placeholder="Select your option">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
           {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here appearance="outline", will add border to the select box.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Aditya! Clean solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it. Easy-peasy!

Add CSS for md-select tag

```
md-select {
               background-color: white;   
               color: black;
               border : 1px solid #666666;

}
```

Comment: how will u eliminate bottom line animation when use click on it?

Answer (score 1):

```
md-select {
   border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
```